# How create a tempory file from base64 encoded string?

Tags: python, windows

How can I create a file into the temporary files from a encoded string and then execute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably be interested in the [`tempfile` module](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html), as well as [`base64`](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) and [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile).

BTW, you may want to provide some more detail about what you're trying to accomplish. This sounds like it has a good chance of being either a bad idea, unnecessary work, or both.

Comment: I want to execute a small executable that will be decoded from an string... I want to decode it to a file in temp files and then run it... could you give me an example?

Comment: `execfile` is for executing a Python script, not a small (Windows) executable.

Comment: @martineau Ah. That wasn't my reading of the question (one of the reasons I said it sounded like a bad idea and asked for clarification). I thought the OP was asking to convert a base64-encoded string into a Python script, store it in a temp file, and execute it. If instead the OP has a binary in base64 encoding, (s)he should probably try [leoluk's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986273/how-create-a-tempory-file-from-base64-encoded-string/6987138#6987138) instead.

Comment: @Hank: I'm not faulting your answer per se, which is completely reasonable given the original question. My comment was primarily for the benefit of the OP, given the more detailed information they provided in their comment regarding what they were wanting to do.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
import tempfile
import subprocess

with tempfile.TemporaryFile(suffix='.exe', delete=False) as tmp:
    tmp.write(EMBEDDED_EXECUTABLE.decode('base64'))
    tmp.close()
    subprocess.Popen(tmp.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

decode the string (pydoc base64); make a tempfile (pydoc tempfile), write the string; and use any number of the os functions to execute it (maybe pydoc os.popen).

Answer (score 0):

You have the Windows tag, so I'll answer accordingly.

You will need to, among other valid possibilities, prefix an underscore before lowercase characters, and replace slashes
with hyphens, in order to make the Base64 sequence a valid filename as well as unique.